# Struts 2 action call loses the xwork i18n language setting

Tags: java, validation, internationalization, struts2, xwork

I call a function "foo.action?request_locale=en" on my form. There is an xwork-validation on that page and I expect to get an validation error in the given language. What I get is a page in Finnish - my browser default language - and I expected one in English.

How it is possible to change the used language on a jsp page (that's where the request_locale comes from) so that the called action from my form will show up with that selected language and not the browser default one?

Some specs:
struts.xml has a line

because my actions are at fi.foo.action directory and i18n resources at fi/foo/package_en.properties and such files.

Validators are at barAction-foo-validation.xml kind of files at fi.foo.action folder.

fi = Finnish

My application works otherwise fine but this language setting is giving wrong language on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `i18n` interceptor is not configured for your action's interceptor stack. The `i18n` interceptor is defined fourth in the `defaultStack`. Make sure you are not overriding the stack for your action. If it appears to be configured, then try setting a breakpoint in the `intercept` method of the `I18nInterceptor` to confirm that it is being invoked. Otherwise, what you have should work.

Comment: I did not have any interceptor config. Now I added one and everything works now. Thanks Steven!

Comment: Now I have com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor and com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor. These work well when I have field errors coming from fooAction-bar-validation kind of validating. I also have action validation and that seemed to override the another validations so that every validation message is shown when action lands with "input" result and fielderror opened to some line. What interceptor would solve the problem? There are so many of them and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Issue solved: I added a 'params' interceptor. It keeps the field errors when landed to an error page.